# protected virtual или private в sealed классе

Tags: c#

В [статье](http://sergeyteplyakov.blogspot.ru/2011/09/dispose-pattern.html) делается акцент на том, что в `sealed` классе метод `Dispose` должен быть `private`, иначе `protected virtual`. Цитирую:

> Этот метод должен быть `protected virtual` для не-`sealed` классов и `private` для `sealed` классов

В чём выигрыш от такого использования?

По сути `protected virtual` всё равно не сможет быть переопределен для `sealed` класса, т.к. нельзя создать наследников. Но если вдруг мы захотим убрать `sealed` с класса, в котором используем, как советуется, `private`, то придется переделывать на `protected virtual`. Почему бы не оставить во всех случаях `protected virtual`?

Comment: Наличие `virtual` в `sealed` классе выглядит не на своём месте — не должно быть там явных виртуальных методов. «Вдруг» `sealed` не убирается, `sealed` это архитектурное решение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Собственно, ответ уже есть, но он несколько завуалирован, и автор ответа не соизволил его привести к более очевидному состоянию. Поэтому отвечу сам.

**`sealed` класс не может содержать определения новых виртуальных функций**. При попытке сделать это будет выведена [ошибка компиляции CS0549](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/exaxze9s.aspx):

> ```
> error CS0549: New virtual member 'member-name' is declared in a sealed class 'class-name'
> ```

Т.о. для ответа на вопрос достаточно было составить элементарный пример и попробовать его скомпилировать. Недопонимание очевидного возникло из-за того, что в [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) и [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) вкладывается несколько разный смысл в ключевое слово `virtual`. Т.е. в c++ в производном классе для переопределённой виртуальной функции можно писать `virtual`, `virtual` + `override`, `override`, а можно и вообще ничего не добавлять - функция всё равно останется виртуальной и переопределённой (при совпадающих сигнатурах). В c# же для переопределённых виртуальных функций надо использовать исключительно `override`.

Хотя причина использование `private` вместо `protected override` всё равно до конца не ясна. Но в такой форме вопроса пока не звучало.

Answer (score 2):

Я думаю, что проблема в русском языке. :) В отличии от английского в русском языке нет столько оттенков долженствования, как в английском. В большинстве случаев слово "должен" используется и как "обязан" и как "лучше так делать".

Просто перепишите для себя эту фразу из статьи как :)

> Этот метод следует определять как protected virtual для не-sealed
>   классов и как private для sealed классов

Дело в том, что если запечатанный класс является производным от другого базового класса, то он может переопределять защищенные виртуальные функции базового класса. Он не может сам объявлять виртуальные функции, так как это не имеет смысла, хотя может объявлять защищенные члены, что также не имеет смысла делать. В последнем случае компилятор выдаст предупреждение.

Comment: Microsoft в FxCop правилах требует  определять метод виртуальным если он реализует интерфейс, либо весь класс определять как sealed.  Возможно, это своего рода отсылка к этому правилу.

Comment: @Uranus Да, если класс может наследоваться, то этот метод должен быть переопределен. Для sealed классов не имеет смысла объявлять метод как защищенный.

Comment: После замены "должен" на "следует" суть вопроса никак не прояснится. Обратите внимание на последний абзац в вопросе.

Comment: @alexolut Компилятор не разрешает объявлять виртуальные защищенные функции в запечатанном классе. Это логично, так как запечатанный класс не наследуется. Тем не менее если запечатанный класс наследует другой класс, то он может переопределять виртуальные функции , ,базового класса. Так же разрешается объявлять защищенными другие члены класса, хотя это тоже не имеет смысла для запечатанного класса.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow если Вы переформулируете ответ, сделав акцент именно на невозможности скомпилировать (ошибка компиляции) `sealed` класс с `virtual` (не `override`) функцией, то, я думаю, смогу его принять. Ситуация с переводом "должен/следует" не отражает реальной сути.